# Web self registration on Xpages

Tags: xpages

I am looking to create an Xpage self registration site that registers users onto the Domino name and address book. I am just doing a proof of concept.

I will put the code below, but it is a fairly simple matter of capturing the user details, dropping their details and password into the NAB and then, hey presto the user should be able to immediately log into the app.nsf.

At the moment I am manually putting the user into a group that is listed in the ACL as manager on app.nsf (for testing, I am putting them in the group prior to creating the user - just mentioning it in case it is important).

It basically works, BUT, there is a rather large delay. As in, it takes many minutes and sometimes more.  After some research I discovered the console command "show nlcache reset" and a lotusscript/java/javascript code version of it. But it seems to have no effect, either coded or manually from the console - (there is also no response from the console that the command has been initiated, just a new line, is this normal?).

The only quirky thing is that the OU=99123456789 (or something similar, it is a company identifier). So a user will look something like this Fred Citizen/99123456789/Domain (don't think this should matter). The user will however log in as "Fred Citizen" and password.

Any ideas?

We are running 9.0.1

Thanks in advance.
Cheers
Damien

Code Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

 <xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoDocument var="userreg" databaseName="names.nsf"
  formName="Person">
  </xp:dominoDocument>
 </xp:this.data>

 <fieldset class="userreg">
  <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
  <xp:inputText id="FirstName" value="#{userreg.FirstName}">
  </xp:inputText>
  <br />
  <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
  <xp:inputText id="LastName" value="#{userreg.LastName}">
  </xp:inputText>
  <br />

  <label for="CompanyName">Company Name - ABN</label>
  <xp:inputText id="CompanyName" value="#{userreg.CompanyName}">
  </xp:inputText>
  <br />
  <label for="Level0_1">Service ID</label>
  <xp:inputText id="Level0_1" value="#{userreg.Level0_1}">
  </xp:inputText>
  <br />
  <label for="HTTPPassword">Password</label>
  <xp:inputText id="HTTPPassword" value="#{userreg.HTTPPassword}"
    password="true">
  </xp:inputText>
  <br />
  <label for="InternetAddress">Email Address</label>
  <xp:inputText id="InternetAddress" value="#{userreg.InternetAddress}">
  </xp:inputText>
  <br />

  <xp:text escape="true" id="type" value="#{userreg.type}"
  rendered="false">
  </xp:text>

  <xp:button value="Register" id="userreg_submit">
   <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
   refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action>


        <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:actionGroup>

                    <xp:modifyField name="type" value="Person">
                    </xp:modifyField>

                    <xp:modifyField name="FullName">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var fullNameArray = new Array();

var first = getComponent("FirstName").getValue();
var last = getComponent("LastName").getValue();
var abn = getComponent("CompanyName").getValue();
fullNameArray[0]= "CN=" + first + " " + last + "/OU=" + abn + "/O=RR1"; 
fullNameArray[1] = first + " " + last;

return fullNameArray;
}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:modifyField>
                    <xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument>

                </xp:actionGroup>

            </xp:actionGroup>

        </xp:actionGroup>
    </xp:this.action>
   </xp:eventHandler>
  </xp:button>
  <xp:br></xp:br>
  <xp:br></xp:br></fieldset></xp:view>
```

Comment: Have you refreshed the *$Users* view in he NAB before sending the *show nlcache reset* command?

Comment: My thought: do not allow users to create any identity, they can make duplicates -> security backdoor.

Comment: Frantisek is right: You should **NOT** allow anonymous users to create a person doc directly in the names.nsf. To be secure, they have to create a request in a different database, and an agent has to process the request in a names.nsf.

Comment: A `show nlcache reset` shouldn't be necessary: as Sven mentioned: do a refresh of the `$Users` view in the directory (and optionally the `$Groups` view). BTW: I don't agree with the two comments above on creating person docs directly, although you might want to add an activation step to the process (send link to email to require activation) and check for duplicate email addresses. I would also consider registering these users in (at least) a separate OU and optionally a secondary directory.

Comment: @MarkLeusink: What happens if a user registers with an already existing InternetAdress?

Comment: Have you seen this project? http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20User%20Selfregister%20and%20Avatar%20App

Comment: In addition to Mark Leusink's suggestion you could also try computewithform(false,false) after your initial save, then refresh the $Users view.  Also, be sure to validate and scrub the values prior to saving them into the directory (make sure active content filtering is turned on for the first/last/email fields etc).

Comment: @SvenHasselbach: that would be one of the things to definitely check before saving the doc. For web users I normally add the e-mail address to both the `InternetAddress` and `MailAddress` fields: that way they can receive mail and login with their e-mail address. I generate a username based on firstname + lastname (and an optional suffix if a user with the same name already exists).

Comment: @MarkLeusink: Don't forget to set the Author fields, otherwise every one can overwrite other person documents (f.e. the HTTP password) by changing the URL parameters.

Comment: Using `sessionAsSigner` to access (read/write) the secondary address book. Anonymous users don't have access to it.

Comment: Thanks all for the info. Obviously there is  a bit more to it than I first thought, thanks for the insight. Summary below.

Comment: 1. Set up a secondary Directory
2.Check for an existing entry in the NAB and give a yes/no at the point of original submission.
3. Provide a activation email. Populate the person record and not forgeting the InternetAddress and the MailAddress, that way people can log in with their email (didn't know that was possible with Domino - thanks @SvenHasselbach:
4. Use sessionAsSigner so Anonymous users can't access user record, set the Authorfield to stop users splattering others users with tricky URL's.
See below

Comment: 5 Update the ($user) and ($Groups) views, maybe a computeWithForm if required on the person record.
6. Should not need a show nlcache reset. 
I will caputre all the info through the Xpage and validate as much as I can there, then send it off to Java to do the rest.  Happy to post the code up when I have it sorted.
I am suprised there is not already a generic solution for this Xpages @PatrickSawyer (I did see that project, but all the documentation is missing and could not get it to run effectively.)  
I love the Xpages community.    
Cheers  
Damien

Comment: @user1539369 Damien, can you post that as the answer to your question, then you can 'accept' it as the answer and the upvotes will pour in. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my portal users registering and have been able to over come this with the following code.  It's virtually instant.  This code is in my register button after my bean creates the user in the nab and updates all the groups, acl etc....

sessionAsSigner.sendConsoleCommand( session.getServerName(), "lo updall yourNabDBName -t ($VIMGroups)" );

sessionAsSigner.sendConsoleCommand( session.getServerName(), "lo updall yourNabDBName -t ($Users)" );

sessionAsSigner.sendConsoleCommand( session.getServerName(), "lo updall yourNabDBName -t ($ServerAccess)" );

sessionAsSigner.sendConsoleCommand( session.getServerName(), "sh nl r" );

Answer (score 0):

For a lotuscript version of this you need to manually refresh a couple of views in the nab and then it worked.

```
Dim nabFullNameView As NotesView
Dim nabServerAccessView As NotesView
Dim nabUsersView As notesview 
Set nabUsersView = dbNAB.GetView("($Users)") 
Set nabFullNameView = dbNAB.GetView("($LDAPCN)")
Set nabServerAccessView = dbNAB.GetView("($ServerAccess)")

Call nabFullNameView.Refresh
Call nabServerAccessView.Refresh
Call nabUsersView.Refresh

'Closing session commits person document to NAB.
Call s.Close
```